# composition of sequences

Tags: calculus, analysis

let $a_n$ be sequence which converges to $L$. What can we say about $(a_n)^n$ I mean it makes sense that if $L<1$ it converges to $0$ and for $L>1$ it diverges to infinity. But why ? How could we prove it ? And how do we generally approach composition of sequences in this case we do have $b_n=x^n$ where as x is a real number. and the composition is $b(a_n)_n$

Comment: Suppose that $|L|\lt1$. Then using the $\epsilon-N$ definition of the limit allows one to say that for all $\epsilon\gt0$ $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$n\ge N\implies (L-\epsilon)^n\lt a_n^n\lt(L+\epsilon)^n$$then we can just choose a suitably small $\epsilon$ to make a conclusion.

Comment: yeah thats a good one. But you cant generlize it hoewever, i just found that out. You always have to have a new apporach to compostions of sequences. An example would be the composition of sequnces where you take the n-th root

Comment: As an aside, If $L=1$ you could have anything be the resulting limit.  Take for example the well known example of $e^x = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$